# Find previous & next entries in alphabetical index for a candidate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, alphabetical

In a database, I have a string field. I want to find previous & next row in alphabetical order for a candidate string that is not in the database. One solution is to insert temporarily this candidate into the database and do an ORDER BY on the field, but this will generate performance issues (doing an insert before each select).
Do you know any other way to perform this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Following might give you some pointers to start with.

```
SELECT MAX(StringField)
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  StringField < Candidate
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(StringField)
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  StringField > Candidate
```

To retrieve the entire record (and assuming your StringFields are unique), you can wrap this into a subquery.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable yt
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT StringField = MAX(StringField)
          FROM   YourTable
          WHERE  StringField < Candidate
          UNION ALL
          SELECT MIN(StringField)
          FROM   YourTable
          WHERE  StringField > Candidate
        ) yts ON yts.StringField = yt.StringField
```

*Note: one optimization might be to compare on all uppercase (or lowercase) characters so Andy & ANDY have equal weight.*